# Ошибка в bash скрипте. Обновляем git репозитории во вложенных папках

Tags: linux, git, bash

У меня есть структура папок с сабмодулем

- sub
- repo1
  -- sub
- repo2
  -- sub
- repo3
  -- sub

Хочу после обновления сабмодуля - пройтись по папкам(репозиториям) и сделать пуш с новым коммитом сабмодуля (обновить его в репозиториях)

Написал bash скрипт без find (выполняю в папке на уровень выше, чем структура выше)

```
for i in */sub; do (echo i; git pull; cd ..; git add .; git commit -m "Update submodule"; git push -u origin master); done
```

Ожидаю:
Пройдусь по всем папкам с сабмодулем, зайду в папку /sub, сделаю там git pull, вернусь на уровень вверх и сделаю коммит.

Что получаю:

> fatal: не найден git репозиторий (или один из родительских каталогов): .git

В моих директориях точно есть **.git**. И если делать эти команды руками - все ок. Я где-то ошибаюсь в путях, но не понимаю где, и как фиксить.

Буду благодарен помощи

Comment: 1) не стоит лепить все в одну строку 2) несложно заметить, что скрипт всегда только поднимается вверх по дереву папок, выполняя `cd ..`

Comment: А не проще использовать `git submodule foreach`?

Comment: после `echo $i` попробуйте поставить `cd $i` тем самым перейдя в нужную директорию(2 пункт комментария **user7860670**). Перебирая в цикле каталоги автоматический вход в них не производится. Поэтому с каждой итерацией цикла вы становитесь все ближе к корневому каталогу системы.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно подсказали в комментах - for не заходит в директории.

Все пофиксилось захождением в `cd $i`

```
for i in */sub; do (echo $i;
cd $i
git checkout master; 
git pull; 
cd ..; 
git add .; 
git commit -m "UPD SUB REPO"; 
git push -u origin master); 
done
```